# Why do I get "nul" when writing to a file?

Tags: java, file

I am using Java `BufferedWriter` to write to a file line by line. The problem is that when I finish writing the file it shows "nul" all over the file.

I do not think the problems is with what I am writing because I double check it with `System.out.print` and it gives me the desired output.

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing `nul` bytes to the stream.

Comment: We need your code to help you

Comment: I do not think I am writing nul bytes because I am verifying what I am writing by printing it to the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is either with what you are writing, or you are forgetting to close the file after writing to it (and it already contains nul from a previous write). If you check the data you're writing with `System.out.print`, then I suppose it's the latter. Make sure you call `close()` on your file before your program exits.